# Title page does not appear in latex beamer

Tags: beamer, titles

My title page does not appear in the pdf output after running latex. As I am using a template I found on the internet and do not have any experience in latex beamer I seem not able to solve this problem.  I included my preamable and MWE below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{default}      
\usecolortheme{default} 
\usefonttheme{default}  
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\graphicspath{ {bwinbe/} }
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{minibox}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}


\logo{\pgfputat{\pgfxy(0,8)}{\pgfbox[right,base]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig/sedes}}}}
\newcommand{\nologo}{\setbeamertemplate{fig/sedes}{}}

\title[slides]{Robust Bootstrapping in Reserve Claims} 
\author{Pieter Krsteff-Jantcheff}
\institute{KU Leuven}
\date{26/06/15 \\
\includegraphics[width=100pt]{fig/sedes}

}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The figure is not available, you should use `demo` option for the `graphicx` package. And there was a `}` missing at `\end{document` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `\maketitle` in a separate frame.

The following is true for the standard classes, I did not check for beamer, but I believe, the procedure is similar

- `\title` only stores the title into a variable `\@title`
- `\author` stores the name(s) into `\@author`
- `\date` saves the specified date.

Storage doesn't mean typesetting. This is the job of `\maketitle`

---

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{default}      
\usecolortheme{default} 
\usefonttheme{default}  
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\graphicspath{ {bwinbe/} }
} 


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{minibox}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}


\logo{\pgfputat{\pgfxy(0,8)}{\pgfbox[right,base]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig/sedes}}}}
\newcommand{\nologo}{\setbeamertemplate{fig/sedes}{}}

\title[slides]{Robust Bootstrapping in Reserve Claims} 
\author{Pieter Krsteff-Jantcheff}
\institute{KU Leuven}
\date{26/06/15 \\
\includegraphics[width=100pt]{fig/sedes}

}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]